# Create image using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there any way to create image through input pixel values by using tensorflow functions? 
I don't mean to generate images like some people did that by applying generative models.

Some functions like "crop_to_bounding_box()" or "extract_image_patches()" which listed in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf just working on existed images, but I want something helps me create a new image out of overlapping patches with arbitrary size and pixel values.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Please add any details or context from your comment to the question directly.